# Checksum/Hash Column in a Many to Many Relation table

Tags: hibernate, spring, hash, many-to-many, integrity

I am currently developing a web project using JSF, Hibernate and Spring with Spring Security and for data integrity i am currently using an extra column in domain tables and generating that column related to the other columns of that tables so i can later check it if any of the data changed externally. I save or update that column according to operation made. My problem is i have it working on simple plain tables but the situation arises when its about many to many midtables. They are generated and updated by hibernate automatically with only composite key on the midtable with no hash column of course. So I have problem about checking if the data changed externally or can not detect deleted rows. I have logs on main object save for example but no logs for midtable entries. Is it possible that i can add a column in those many to many tables by hibernate and save their entry logs so i can check up later on?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use SQL triggers, although this would log all actions of course, not just the external changes...